# Docker and symfony

Tags: php, symfony, docker, dockerfile

I'm struggling with Docker.

I'm tring to create an image to work on symfony project and to learn Docker in the same time.
Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7-apache

LABEL Description = "This image is used to start Symfony3 project"

ENV DIRPATH /var/www/html

# apt-get command
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    vim \
    git \
 && apt-get clean

# Install Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
RUN mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

# Install the Symfony Installer
RUN curl -LsS http://symfony.com/installer -o /usr/local/bin/symfony
RUN chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/symfony
```

I build the image with the command:

```
docker build -t symfony .
```

Works well! Cool!

I'm create a container with:

```
docker run --name symfony -d -v "$PWD":/var/www/html -p 80:80 symfony
```

Works well also. The web server is running on the good port.

I can go in my container with:

```
docker exec -ti symfony bash
```

But when I'm trying to do a composer update, I have some errors:

```
Failed to download symfony/symfony from dist: Could not decompress the archive, enable the PHP zip extension.
A php.ini file does not exist. You will have to create one.
```

How can I create the php.ini in Dockerfile?

I also think that I have an issue with permission. 
When I'm trying to the web/app_dev.php I have this message:

```
You are not allowed to access this file. Check app_dev.php for more information.
```

Comment: I'm not sure with docker but usually put `php.ini` in `web/` folder to overwrite default php.ini. In your case have you check zip extension ? Try run `php -m | grep zip` to check you have zip installed.

Comment: Hi FYI: Every line in a docker file will be a new image. If you have multiple &amp;#39;run&amp;#39; commands that pretty much do the same, you can simply do &amp;#39;&amp;amp;&amp;amp;&amp;#39; and use &amp;#39;\&amp;#39; for newlines

ex.

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php && mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ADD a custom `php.ini` configuration specifing it in the dockerfile, 
As Example, you can take a look at [this repo](https://github.com/lepiaf/docker-symfony2#modifyextend-this-image) for this example:

<kbd>dokerfile</kbd>

```
# install a few more PHP extensions
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y php5-imagick php5-gd php5-mongo php5-curl php5-mcrypt php5-intl

# copy a custom config file from the directory where this Dockerfile resides to the image
COPY php.ini /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini
```

You can find various approach and various sample on the net.

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Next to the missing `php.ini` file you should also install zip so you can download from dist, i.e.

```
RUN docker-php-ext-install zip
```

Which will install and enable the PHP zip extension which is requested in your error message.